# Eclipse Plugin Developement: How to programatically add a dependency to a Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin called "A"

A allows a user to parse a config file - it then creates a folder with a set of java files in it that should be ready to run.  It also creates (copies really) the necessary Jar file into the project.

My question is: how do I make the project notice that the Jar file is there? Googling for this gives me hundreds of hits for either "How to add a dependency from one plugin to another" or "how to add a dependency on a jar file using the mouse" - but what I want to do is write some code to programmatically make a project depend on a jar file that I've just programmatically copied in.

Can this be done? If so how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a Java project, you can programmatically add entries to the classpath of the project. Eclipse jdt allows adding entries via the JavaCore class. You can get hold of the IJavaProject using JavaCore.getJavaProject API and then manipulate it's  classpath using the set ClasspathEntries API. Look in the jdt help for examples on how to do this